# html file by constant R

Tags: android

I have a html file. I would like to reference it with the constant `R` I tried the following code :

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.3);
```

I created a folder `raw` in the directory `res` and I included the `file3.html`

EDIT

...but don't work!!the word "R.raw.3" is underlined

EDIT

I have another question. I have an array with the names of files to be accessed. How can I access with a statement like that?
   getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xxx);

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Be more specific when asking question, so that others can understand your question properly.

Comment: sorry...but don't work!!the word "R.raw.3" is underlined

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Have you tried cleaning your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file named **file3.html** in your raw folder under res folder your R.java file will contain a raw class like:

```
 public static final class raw {
        public static final int file3=0x7f040000;
    }
```

So, you should use `R.raw.file3` instead of `R.raw.3` because **3** is not a valid resource name, if you rename your file to 3.html you will find a **invalid VariableDeclaratorId** error in your R.java file

Comment: If you want id from resource name use [public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your html file in the assets folder. In their you can reference it using the AssetManager.